# Giving score to entities in certain radius of players

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So my idea was when you are wearing a chestplate flame particles spawn around them

```
/execute @a[score_ARMOR_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /particle flame ~ ~-1 ~ .01 5 5 5 50
```

then if the score of "ARMOR" is 1 it detects all entities in a radius of 5 from the player

```
/execute @a[score_ARMOR_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /testfor @e[type=!Player,r=5]
```

it doesn't update though even though I'm standing right next to a cow it won't give me an output and the fill clock is on. What I wanted to know can I give a score to those entities, so I can

```
/execute @e[score_BurnMobs_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /setblock fire ~ ~-1 ~ 0 replace air
```

Comment: A general rule in Minecraft commands is that you never want to use `testfor`, unless you *know exactly that you have to*. It's a fairly limited command which doesn't actually do that much, and most of what it does is done better by `execute`.

Comment: I believe your `testfor` does not update because you don't actually have a command block running `testfor`, it's running `execute`, which presumably tells you something like "Executed <command> as Veritas025". It does not care what the result of the command itself was.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Since `scoreboard` is a command, it can be chained off execute just like any other command.

What you want to do is as simple as:

```
/execute @a[score_ARMOR_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players set @e[type=!Player,r=5] BurnMobs 1
```

Comment: Well Obviously I was overthinking my problem....Thanks for the command